# Error returning integer as number of items in section

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an iPad app, using Storyboards, Tab Bar and XCode 4.5.  One of my scenes has a UITableView in the upper left quadrant, with labels and UITextBoxes in the right upper quadrant.

When I click on the second tab, I am taken to the scene described above.  This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL"];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

    return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 4;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {

    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.item];
    return cell;
}
```

This is the interface definition:

```
@interface ClientViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource> {

}
```

This is the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView
>   collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7d925b0'

As you see, I used the same code for numberOfSectionsInCollectionView.  I have researched SO and Google and found nothing that applies.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you specified the wrong pointer as your data delegate?

Comment: That's interesting... I have updated the question to show the interface definition.  Delegates are not one of my strong points (been there many times and still really don't understand them).  However, I notice that I have no method to handle the delegate (hope that's using the right terminology)... so, where do I go from here?

Comment: There are two delegates to set.  One is the `delegate`, and one is the `dataSource`.  Generally, both should be set to point to your view controller (ie, `self` in most circumstances).

Comment: Please put this in an answer... that's exactly what's wrong... thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please post how you fixed this. I've added the delegates but the error is still occurring. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two delegates to set. One is the `delegate`, and one is the `dataSource`. Generally, both should be set to point to your view controller (ie, `self` in most circumstances).